# How to make Title Filed Required

Tags: 8, migrations

I have migrated my Drupal 7 website to Drupal 8. The content types are showing title as optional and when we save a node without adding the title it's giving the fatal error.

How can we make the title field compulsory?

**Note**: I know title field is required by default, and it is required by default in my Drupal 7 site. But after migrating the site to Drupal 8 it's not showing required. Is it possible if export content types configuration from my new site and edit the configuration and import them again to fix this issue?

Comment: It should be required by default, there must be something in code possibly doing a form alter and setting the required value to false

Comment: As already said. Node titles are required by default. We know absolutely nothing about your setup, so it's impossible to solve your issue from afar without lots a back-and-forth clarification in comments. Apart from that this issue simply is too specific and most likely won't help others. Find out what makes your title field unrequired and this will fix your issue. Maybe some custom module, maybe some automatic node title contrib module, who knows ...

Comment: I know title field is required by default, and it is required by default in my Drupal 7 site. But after migrating the site to Drupal 8 it's not showing required. Is it possible if export content types configuration from my new site and edit the configuration and import them again to fix this issue?

Answer (score 1):

You can indeed edit the exported config and then re-import it to make the title field mandatory.

**Always be careful when editing config directly.**

The config files generally follow the naming convention `core.base_field_override.<entity_type>.<bundle>.title.yml`.

There should be a `required` key which is set to `false`. Simply change `false` to `true`, save and then re-import your config.